# Some environmental variables accessible, others not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I have a rails app and am trying to use an environmental variable (API key) inside of a controller and it is failing. Debugging shows it's value to be nil. Weird thing is that other keys from that file are accessible, so I am not really understanding why. They are all in my secrets.yml file.

I have tried accessing it using both `ENV["STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY"]` and `Rails.application.secrets.stripe_test_secret_key` and both come back nil. I get the error:

`No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.`

using the better errors gem. How do I make these available throughout my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY` in the environment running the Rails app.

Check out the [Choices gem](https://github.com/mislav/choices), it makes overriding env vars pretty easy.

You can set the env vars on the CLI in development like this:

```bash
$ STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY=abc123 rails s
```

If you are using Rbenv, you can create a `.rbenv-vars` file in the root of your project that contains one env var per line like this:

```bash
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_pass@localhost:3306/dev_db
STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY=abc123
SOME_OTHER_VAR=foo
```

Comment: my `STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY` is readable, as well as my `STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY `...there must have been something I did with them that made them available, with out the use of a gem. Is there a terminal command to accomplish this?

Comment: You can set the env vars on the command line that you use to start your rails server in development. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: That looks familiar!! Let me give that a go!

Comment: That was it!! I have been googling for over an hour and a half, thank you SO much!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!